# Function Header vs Include Header php? - Upsides and Downsides

Tags: php, performance, caching

I am mainly looking for Performance, Website Cacheing, Ease of typing & Security  - Upsides and Downsides

Split up the files and throw them in as includes and seems to be a shared preference

```
<?php
include('header.php');//and whatever includes inside 
include('footer.php');//and whatever includes inside 
?>
```

VS

Making them into functions and calling them while in one file where you can check values and share them between the two functions such as multi-style choices

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/more-functions.php';
if(isset($_cookie['style']) || isset($_session['style'])){
    if(isset($_cookie['style'])){$style = $_cookie['style']}else{$style = $_session['style']}
}
function siteheader($style){
    if(!isset($style)){$style = 'default';}
    print ('<http>');//insert rest of header
}
function sitefooter($style){
    if(!isset($style)){$style = 'default';}
    print ('</http>');//insert rest of footer
}
?>
```

Comment: Performance: there may be slight differences, but nothing so substantial that you could detect it. Also: benchmark it. Caching: no influence whatsoever. Ease of typing: decide for yourself. Security: ??? "Security" of what?

Comment: Just a side-note, you can't access cookies/session while the variable is lowercase. It has to be `$_COOKIE`/`$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include('header.php');//and whatever includes inside  
include('footer.php');//and whatever includes inside
```

This breaks [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

While it's almost inevitable that using a header and footer, whether explicitly or implicitly invoked, will result in badly formed HTML fragments, when you explicitly invoke it (as a function/method) you can at least have the two fragments defined inside the same file.

Performance won't differ significantly.